# Django REST Api with Django templates?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

Does it even make sense to create a REST Api in Django and have your front end as Django templates?

Comment: You can have templates for browser and API for, for example, mobile devices. So I guess it makes sense in this scenario :)

Comment: If you want it just for browser, is there any point of creating an api?

Comment: Yeah, you could have many different frontend applications with the same backend when you have REST API (for example written in Angular, React, Vue.js and so on).

It depends on your needs of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you have front as only(!!!) Django templates, than **no**